# Cursor data transfer in android

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying to transfer some rows from one cursor to other.

```
Like Suppose i get one cursor from database and now i want to create one cursor based
on the previous cursor 
Lets say, In  First cursor 
    1. A>12  Transfer all the values of first row to cursor B.
    2. A>12 Transfer all the values of first row to cursor B.
    3. A>12 Not true move next.
    4. A>12 Transfer all the values of first row to cursor B.
```

Answer (score 1):

A cursor cannot be updated, because it does not stores all the values (it's why for large amout of rows, Cursor are more efficient than Lists).

What you can do is update the datas in your database so the data will not be in B anymore and will switch to A, then do an other request.

If you don't want to modify datas, then you can do it by putting datas from your Cursor to a List.

Comment: The last option i have is to put in list only but if i can put data in cursor will be beautifull